# Spring Batch memory leak - XML to database using ItemWriter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, out-of-memory, spring-batch

I had a problem with a Spring Batch job for reading a large XML file (a few million records) and saving the records from it to a database. The job uses chunk of 100 elements and `MultiResourceItemReader` for reading the XML, `ItemProcessor` for processed records and `ItemWriter` for writing records to the database using JPA and `EntityManager`. The problem is that when call persist operation the job ends up with `OutOfMemoryError` (I tried to comment writer phase and the problem does not occur).

```
public class MyClassWriter implements ItemWriter<MyObject> {

    @Autowired
    private MyDelegate delegate;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends MyObject> items) throws Exception {
    ...    
    List<MyObject> foos2 = (List<MyObject>)(List<?>)items; 
    delegate.setInsert(foos2); 
    ...
    }
```

and

```
public void setInsert(List<MyObject> list) {
    for (MyObject el : list) {
        em.persist(el);
    }
    em.flush();
    em.clear(); //I tried to call clear operation too, but not solved problem
}
```

Any suggestion for me?

Comment: Which `ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<T>` are you using as your delegate to your `MultiResourceItemReader`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the OutOfMemoryException is caused when trying to save too many items at once, try saving the items in batches:

```
int c = 0;

for (MyObject mo : list) {
  em.persist(mo);
  if (++c % 1000 == 0) {
    em.flush();
  }
}

// save any remaining items
em.flush();
```

Comment: @Fra83 - Does this solution works for you ? Or you can use `MultiResourceItemReader` too

Comment: @artemisian Unfortunately your solution does not solve my problem :(

Comment: Try lowering the batch size from 1000 to 10 for example

Comment: Batch size is 100 not 1000. However I already lowered batch size from 100 to 10, but nothing..

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace of the OutOfMemoryError?